# Use validateJS input one of two fields when one is a file

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, input

I am using validate.js for a form and would like to validate this field, so that the submit button becomes active.

```
<input type="text" name="lib" id="lib" value=""  required="required"/>
```

The input value is generated from activation from another piece of jquery  script:

```
$('#lib').val("1");
```

Even though the value field fills, validate.js doesn't recognise it. If I type manually, no problem the submit button becomes active.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use **class** attribute instead of using **id**
try this:

```
$(.lib).val('1');
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Why would that make any difference? The field is already filling. Just to make sure I tried and doesn't work.

Comment: In js, classes attributes are reusable as compared to ids. It happened to me that's why I told you to do that.

Comment: Sure, but this is only used once and as I say it visibly fills the field but doesn't get validated as filled.